# Fixed div on scroll and change state using CSS and sticky.js

Tags: javascript, css, fixed

I'm currently using [sticky.js](http://stickyjs.com/) to fix a div to the top of my screen when I scroll. This works perfectly and I wouldn't want to change it but I would like to apply some css to the div to effect some change when it sticks.

I have tried implementing some JavaScript to the sticky script but it's still not working.

This is what I have now:

HTML

```
<div class="header"><div class="small_logo"><a href="/"><img src=""></a></div></div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$(".header").sticky({
     topSpacing: 0,
     success: function() {
            $('.header').addClass("wide");
            $('.small_logo').fadeIn("slow");    
            }
    });
  });
```

I'm sure it's just a simple javascript format issue but I just can't seem to find the right syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to @Alex's point, the documentation does not describe any success option that you have used in your code.

The correct way would be to use the events that have been [described in the documentation on github](https://github.com/garand/sticky#events)

I've given an example below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $(".header").sticky({topSpacing: 0});
  $('.header').on('sticky-start', function() {
    $(".small_logo img").fadeIn("slow");
  });
  
  $('.header').on('sticky-end', function() {
    $(".small_logo img").fadeOut("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
  .header {
    background: #EEE;
    height: 100px;
  }

  .small_logo img{
    height: 100px;
    display: none;
  }

  .body {
    height: 1000px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.sticky/1.0.4/jquery.sticky.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
      <div class="small_logo">
  <!--       <a href="/"> -->
          <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YCaGYUIfdy4/maxresdefault.jpg">
  <!--       </a>       -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="body"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you see the brief [documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/garand/sticky#events)?

According to the section about events you will need to do the following:

```
$('.header').on('sticky-start', function() { // your code });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [simple example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_navbar_hide_scroll). Or this code:

```js
<script>
  var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
  window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
      $('.header').css({top: '0px'});
    } else {
      $('.header').css({top: '-50px'});
    }
    prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant info in your answer.

Comment: Hey @Mr.Js thanxx for the quick response, but am fine with the sticky.js I just want to add to it to create the effect I stated

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
})

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
}
```

apply css to sticky class for effect

Comment: Hey @Poulima, thank you for this but would I have to stop using sticky.js to do this

Comment: Actually this is most easy way to stick div on scroll. Without using sticky.js you can do it, it worked for me